# Python - Get Path of File from inside of Module

Tags: python, python-3.x

so after some time searching i was unable to find how to get a path of file which imported module
every question was about how get path of module but not about it does anyone know how access it or get some normal way ?

My Module is used to get relative path but i cant get a folder in which is file using that module

I tried get Parent of Module and some os.path methods but None returned needed data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You find the path of the current module in  `__file__`. If any of your functions in the module needs the path of the calling module, you should provide it with a parameter.

Comment: you can use `import os print(os.path.abspath('.'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.argv[0]`, e.g.

```
def path_of_main_script():
    return sys.argv[0]
```